# sbt assembly error- out of memory

Tags: maven, sbt, sbt-assembly

My ultimate goal is to run iPython with spark. I have a Mac (El Capitan) with Anaconda, Spark 1.6.0, py4j 0.9, and jdk 1.8.0_73.

When I run `sbt assembly`, I get an error for out of memory. I tried setting `SBT_OPTS` but it did not help.

```
$ echo $SBT_OPTS 
-Xmx2G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:PermSize=256M -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M`
```

So I tried to install using maven.

```
./make-distribution.sh --name custom-spark --tgz -Psparkr -Phadoop-2.4 -Phive -Phive-thriftserver -Pyarn
```

This did not work for me either. I get the following error

```
[INFO] Spark Project Unsafe ............................... SUCCESS [  9.739 s]
[INFO] Spark Project Core ................................. FAILURE [01:13 min]
.
.
.
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:54 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-02-12T01:05:51-08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 55M/685M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:exec (sparkr-pkg) on project spark-core_2.10: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 127 (Exit value: 127) -> [Help 1]
```

I tried to search for error 127 but haven't found any that solved my problem. I wonder if I have some kind of firewall setting (have been using home network)

Any help/pointer will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by making .sbt_config file, which contains

```
SBT_OPTS="-Xmx2G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=2G -Xss2M"
```